# When to use batchSize and limit in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am little bit confuse in `batchSize` cursor method and `limit`.

```
db.inventory.find().batchSize(10)
```

and limit

```
db.inventory.find().limit(10)
```

What is difference between both the above queries? And when to use `batchSize` and `limit`.

Thank you

Comment: @JohnnyHK The main question here is ***"when to use"***?

Comment: When you need that functionality? :) Is there something about the function of the two that still isn't clear after reading the linked dupe?

Comment: Thank you for replying...  I ran this `db.getCollection('exercises').find({}).batchSize(25)` in robomongo but it still returns all the documents?  ***When you need that functionality?*** and this is my question please give some hint

Comment: With `batchSize` you're just telling the driver how many of the total results to get at a time over the wire, it doesn't affect the overall total (which is what `limit` does). If your docs are large and your network is slow, you may want to reduce the batchSize to reduce the response time to accessing the first doc of the results.